# About django wrapper example in spyne documentation

Tags: python, django, spyne

I have just tried the django wrapper example in spyne documentation; but I don't understand it very well. I already tried the hello world example, and I could use suds to test the Spyne service, according to documentation, with the following code lines:

```
from suds.client import Client
hello_client = Client('http://localhost:7789/?wsdl')
print hello_client.service.say_hello("Dave", 5),
```

I know the default address for a django server is `http://localhost:8000`, therefore I assumed that I only had to change the second code line; but this thing didn't work. Which could be the code for trying the Spyne service with the suds client? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what errors do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at this file
https://github.com/arskom/spyne/blob/master/examples/django/rpctest/urls.py

...I think you may have to change your url above to

```
hello_client = Client('http://localhost:8000/api/?wsdl')
```